# Nested find on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, find

I have the following insert on MongoDB.

```
db.country.insert({
    "name":{"common":"Madrid"},
    "currency":["EUR"],
    "languages":{"mad":"Madrid","spa":"Spanish"},
    "region":"Europe"
})
```

I want to find that entry if `Madrid` is inside `languages` with a `find`, but I don't know how to perform a query like that. I've been searching for it, but I didn't find any solution that is working for me.

Comment: Your model doesn't seem adapted for what you want to achieve. A more sensible query would be to check if `mad` exists in the languages object, which you can do with `find({'languages.mad': {$exists: true}})`. Also, is there a reason for `languages` not being an array?